# Submit a Python script to google compute VM instance, run, store the results and stop the instance

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform

I am new to the google cloud. I want to run a Python script on the VM instance (at the end of the Python script, the result will be save as a file). Since the script will run a long time, I want to submit it from my local Linux console with `gcloud` commands. And after the script finishes running, the VM instance automatically stops to avoid extra cost, and the result file should be stored somewhere so I can get to it later.

I'm not familiar with Bash commands, I assume I can submit a ".sh" file? What should I put in the file and How can I submit the task to VM instance? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is in the python script?  how long does it takes? did you tried cloud functions with cloud trigger?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve your desired task by taking advantage of [Cloud Functions Storage Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) and the [instance.stop method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/stop) from the Compute Engine API.

The general idea will be to start the instance with the [gcloud compute instance start](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/start) command, then take advantage of the [gcloud compute ssh with the --command flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#--command) to run your script within the instance. Make the Python script within the instance [upload the file to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample) using the Cloud Storage Client Library for Python and take advantage of the Cloud Functions Storage [Object Finalize](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize) event to serve as a trigger to call the Cloud Function and stop the instance.

1. [Create a VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#startinginstancewithimage) and make sure that you have [setup a Firewall rule to allow SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#startinginstancewithimage) (allow ingress traffic on TCP port 22) and most importantly that it has enough scopes assigned for write (although I'd recommend you to allow [read/write](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write) operations) to Cloud Storage Buckets. This can be accomplished by making sure that you are using Compute Engine default service account (with at least the Editor and Storage Object Admin roles assigned) for Identity and API access. If you are using the Console simply select `Set access for each API` and choose `Read Write` for storage.
2. [Create a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) making sure you set the Access Control settings to [Uniform](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#choose_between_uniform_and_fine-grained_access).
3. Use the console or the `gcloud compute ssh your-instance` to ssh into your VM and create your Python script (don't forget to make it executable by running `chmod +x your-script.py`). For example, the following script will be stored in the default directory and have the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from time import sleep
from google.cloud import storage
bucket_name = 'test-bucket-vmss'
destination_blob_name = 'myuploadedfile.txt'
file_name = 'example_upload_file.txt'
#Create a file
f=open(file_name,'w+')
f.write('This is an example file to upload to Google Cloud Storage')
f.close()
#Simulates that the file takes 5 minutes to be created
sleep(300)
#Upload the file to Google Cloud Storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
blob.upload_from_filename("./"+file_name)
```

4. [Create a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/console#create_a_function) by choosing an [Object Finalize Storage Trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) (notice that default is HTTP), by making sure you set the timeout to 9 minutes ([max allowed for the time being](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout)), choose Python 3.7 for runtime and if you leave the App Engine default service account for authentication make sure that it has the `compute.instances.stop` permission assigned.
   a. The main.py part of the Cloud Function should contain:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from time import sleep

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
# Project ID for this request.
project = 'you-project-name'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.
# The name of the zone for this request.
zone = 'the-zone-of-the-vm'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.
# Name of the instance resource to stop.
instance = 'the-name-of-the-vm'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.


def hello_gcs(event, context):
    """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    file = event
    print(f"The file: {file['name']} was uploaded to the bucket.")
    #Stopping VM after the file is processed
    sleep(5)
    request = service.instances().stop(project=project, zone=zone, instance=instance)
    response = request.execute()
    print("The VM was stopped.")
```

b. The requirements.txt part of the Cloud Function should contain:

```
google-api-python-client
oauth2client
```

and deploy the function.

5. From your local environment where the [Google Cloud SDK is installed](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) make a script or simply run:

```
### Start the Compute engine instance
gcloud compute instances start the-name-of-the-vm --zone=the-zone-of-the-vm
### Take advantage of the --command flag to run your script within the Compute Engine instance
gcloud compute ssh instance-2 --command="./your-script.py &" --zone=the-zone-of-the-vm
```

Once the file is uploaded to the Cloud Storage bucket the Cloud Function will take care of stopping the instance.

Comment: This did not work for me. The step 5 caused an issue. I was able to start the instance `gcloud compute ssh test-instance --command="./test.py &" --zone=us-central1-a` but not  able to run the script inside the instance `gcloud compute ssh test-instance --command="./test.py &" --zone=us-central1-a`.  `bash: ./test.py: No such file or directory` is the error. but `ls` shows the file

Comment: You need to make sure to use the correct path to the file. My example uses relative paths, but logging to the VM through the GCP console, looking for the file and running readlink -f test.py should print you the full path so that you can modify the --command flag of the gcloud to the correct full path.